# PostgreSQL generates an empty 20-byte gzipped backup file

Tags: postgresql, database-backups, jelastic

We manage several Java+PostgreSQL environments in Jelastic. Our PaaS provider uses Jelastic platform version 5.4.

In each environment, we have a cron task that calls a shell script to generate a daily gzipped database back-up via `pg_dump` for PostgreSQL 9.4. This script has been running for years, literally, but recently it stopped working. The script looks like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
DATE=`date +"%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S"`
DB_NAME="my-backup"
FILE="$DB_NAME-$DATE.backup.gz"
BASE_DIR="/var/lib/jelastic/backup"
BACKUP_FILE_PATH=$BASE_DIR/$FILE
pg_dump --verbose --format=custom $DB_NAME | gzip > $BACKUP_FILE_PATH
```

The only thing that has changed recently has to do with an increased `shared_buffers` value in `postgresql.conf`, which is a change we performed based on instructions provided by Jelastic. We did try reversing the change on `shared_buffers` to return it to its default value for Jelastic environments, with no positive effects on back-ups.

Now, the generated backup file (gzipped) is just 20 bytes long, and the whole backup process takes much less time than we would expect, as our database is large (over 1.5GB) and contains BLOBs. The file extracted from the GZIP is empty.

In `pg_dump` verbose output there's nothing out of the ordinary:

```
pg_dump: reading schemas
pg_dump: reading user-defined tables
pg_dump: reading extensions
pg_dump: reading user-defined functions
pg_dump: reading user-defined types
pg_dump: reading procedural languages
pg_dump: reading user-defined aggregate functions
pg_dump: reading user-defined operators
pg_dump: reading user-defined operator classes
pg_dump: reading user-defined operator families
pg_dump: reading user-defined text search parsers
pg_dump: reading user-defined text search templates
pg_dump: reading user-defined text search dictionaries
pg_dump: reading user-defined text search configurations
pg_dump: reading user-defined foreign-data wrappers
pg_dump: reading user-defined foreign servers
pg_dump: reading default privileges
pg_dump: reading user-defined collations
pg_dump: reading user-defined conversions
pg_dump: reading type casts
pg_dump: reading table inheritance information
pg_dump: reading event triggers
pg_dump: finding extension members
pg_dump: finding inheritance relationships
pg_dump: reading column info for interesting tables
pg_dump: finding the columns and types of table "databasechangeloglock"
pg_dump: finding the columns and types of table "databasechangelog"
pg_dump: finding the columns and types of table "compania"
pg_dump: finding default expressions of table "compania"
pg_dump: finding the columns and types of table "comprobante"
pg_dump: finding default expressions of table "comprobante"
pg_dump: finding the columns and types of table "estado_comprobante"
pg_dump: finding default expressions of table "estado_comprobante"
pg_dump: finding the columns and types of table "usuario"
pg_dump: finding default expressions of table "usuario"
pg_dump: finding the columns and types of table "clave_contingencia"
pg_dump: finding default expressions of table "clave_contingencia"
pg_dump: finding the columns and types of table "latido_integrador"
pg_dump: finding default expressions of table "latido_integrador"
pg_dump: finding the columns and types of table "comprobante_importado"
pg_dump: finding default expressions of table "comprobante_importado"
pg_dump: finding the columns and types of table "estado_comprobante_importado"
pg_dump: finding default expressions of table "estado_comprobante_importado"
pg_dump: finding the columns and types of table "tarea_comprobante_importado"
pg_dump: finding default expressions of table "tarea_comprobante_importado"
pg_dump: finding the columns and types of table "usuario_compania"
pg_dump: finding default expressions of table "usuario_compania"
pg_dump: flagging inherited columns in subtables
pg_dump: reading indexes
pg_dump: reading indexes for table "databasechangeloglock"
pg_dump: reading indexes for table "compania"
pg_dump: reading indexes for table "comprobante"
pg_dump: reading indexes for table "estado_comprobante"
pg_dump: reading indexes for table "usuario"
pg_dump: reading indexes for table "clave_contingencia"
pg_dump: reading indexes for table "latido_integrador"
pg_dump: reading indexes for table "comprobante_importado"
pg_dump: reading indexes for table "estado_comprobante_importado"
pg_dump: reading indexes for table "tarea_comprobante_importado"
pg_dump: reading indexes for table "usuario_compania"
pg_dump: reading constraints
pg_dump: reading foreign key constraints for table "compania"
pg_dump: reading foreign key constraints for table "comprobante"
pg_dump: reading foreign key constraints for table "estado_comprobante"
pg_dump: reading foreign key constraints for table "usuario"
pg_dump: reading foreign key constraints for table "clave_contingencia"
pg_dump: reading foreign key constraints for table "latido_integrador"
pg_dump: reading foreign key constraints for table "comprobante_importado"
pg_dump: reading foreign key constraints for table "estado_comprobante_importado"
pg_dump: reading foreign key constraints for table "tarea_comprobante_importado"
pg_dump: reading foreign key constraints for table "usuario_compania"
pg_dump: reading triggers
pg_dump: reading triggers for table "compania"
pg_dump: reading triggers for table "comprobante"
pg_dump: reading triggers for table "estado_comprobante"
pg_dump: reading triggers for table "usuario"
pg_dump: reading triggers for table "clave_contingencia"
pg_dump: reading triggers for table "latido_integrador"
pg_dump: reading triggers for table "comprobante_importado"
pg_dump: reading triggers for table "estado_comprobante_importado"
pg_dump: reading triggers for table "tarea_comprobante_importado"
pg_dump: reading triggers for table "usuario_compania"
pg_dump: reading rewrite rules
pg_dump: reading large objects
pg_dump: reading dependency data
pg_dump: saving encoding = UTF8
pg_dump: saving standard_conforming_strings = on
pg_dump: saving database definition
```

Also, the PostgreSQL 9.4 logs than can be accessed on Jelastic show no relevant messages that may give us a clue as to what might be happening.

In an attempt to "fix" this, we have performed PostgreSQL maintenance procedures, including `vacuumlo` and `vacuumdb --full`, to no avail. There's plenty of available storage space available for the backup file, so that should not be the cause of the problem.

Any ideas about why this might be happening? What should we look for, and where? As this is a critical issue, we would appreciate any pointers.

Comment: Is this just happening in one environment of your several?

Comment: reading your post again, try specifying user for pg_dump like "pg_dump -U  postgres  ... etc"

Comment: @Slumdog It is happening in a couple of environments where the only change has been the modification of the `shared-buffers` value.

Comment: @Slumdog Also, I do not specify the `-U` switch because I have made some changes to `pg_hba.conf` to allow for unsupervised backup generation via the cron job. As I mentioned in the original post, the script has always worked, and it is exactly the same as the one that works just fine in other environments (my deployment procedure is automated.) The only difference is the `shared-buffers` value. The databases are large (several GB in size), but that didn't seem to cause any trouble before.

Comment: hi, @Esteban, how look for you the postgres file on cron folder??

Answer (score 1):

The first thing you need to do is to change the file pg_hba.conf (allow connections without a password through sockets):

```
CT-42366 ~# cat ./backup.sh 
local    all all                  trust
host     all all     127.0.0.1/32 ident
host     all all     ::1/128      ident
host     all all     0.0.0.0/0    md5
```

After that restart "postgresql" service:

```
service postgresql restart
```

Then, if your login to the database is different from "root", use this modified script:

```
CT-42366 ~# cat ./backup.sh 
#!/bin/bash
DATE=date +"%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S"
DB_NAME="db_name"
LOGIN="db_login"
FILE="$DB_NAME-$DATE.backup.gz"
BASE_DIR="/var/lib/jelastic/backup"
BACKUP_FILE_PATH=$BASE_DIR/$FILE
pg_dump --user=$LOGIN --format=custom --dbname=$DB_NAME | gzip > 
$BACKUP_FILE_PATH
```

We hope this helps you solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks for the modified script, but I don't think it is a solution in my case. As explained in the original post, the script has not changed and has been working for a few years. Originally I did follow the instructions on the Jelastic documentation, which included a change to `pg_hba.conf`. I am not getting permission errors with `pg_dump`, and therefore I don't need the modified script; actually, `pg_dump` produces a "normal" output (which I included above). The only change was the `shared_buffers` value, but even after reverting that change, `pg_dump` is generating empty backup files.

Comment: You still need to try variations directly in Postgresql and tell us what you have tried, we can't tell from your comments. So far all I can read from your replies are what you think is best rather than actual results. Try logging connection info at least in Postgresql, comparing it to a working server.

Comment: Your problem is that you have the pg_hba.conf file configured by default in environments where backups do not work. Check it out and, if necessary, change it according to the answer I gave above.

Comment: hi, @Jelactic, according with https://docs.jelastic.com/postgresql-backup-restore, how look postgres file on cron folder to run bash file??

Comment: @meyquel, it's enough to specify a path to your script in postgres cron file. _* * * * * /path_to_script/script.sh_ works fine for us (script.sh should be executable). If such approach doesn't work please refer the official cron documentation